# Deserialize XML string in Silverlight

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight

InC# WinForms I can derialize my XML file like so

```
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);

    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fi.FullName);


    XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Scene));

    Scene scene = new Scene();
    scene = (Scene)reader.Deserialize(file);


    file.Close();
    file.Dispose();
```

But in Silverlight I have to download the XML and read it as a String so I need to be able to Deserialize a XML String. Not sure how its done.

Something like this would be good

```
    StringReader text = new StringReader(fi.FullName);


    XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Scene));

    Scene scene = new Scene();
    scene = (Scene)reader.Deserialize(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

In silverlight,

```
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(xml))) {

            DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());

            return (object)dcs.ReadObject(ms);

    }
```

Say Person is the name of your class,

```
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(xml)))
       {
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(person.GetType());
       return (person)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

       }
```

Comment: do I just replace obj.GetType() with my class,? what is obj ?

Comment: Is this serializing or deserializing. I only have the XML string

Comment: This is deserialization, if you want to serialize the result object again you can use the DataContractSerializer